# How to find out exact version of iPhone SDK for conditional compilation?

Tags: iphone, conditional-compilation

I'm looking for a macro that specified the exact version of the iPhone SDK used for compilation. This is needed because when compiling with (and only with) SDK 3.0, I need to add some additional code.

`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is not the right choice here, since it can be set by the user with parameter `-mmacosx-version-min`. For example, a user can compile with min version `-mmacosx-version-min=3.0` in SDK 3.1, so a check for `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED == 30000` would be true, even if the user is compiling with SDK 3.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following macros

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_3_0

    NSLog(@"iPhone OS Ver is 3.0");

#else

     NSLog(@"Not iPhone OS 3.0");

#endif
```

Comment: __IPHONE_3_0 is also defined in iPhone SDK 3.1, so this does not work.